# Aggregate functions with conditions

Tags: mysql, aggregate-functions

I have a table which contains rows for different events during a day.

```
+------------+---------------------+---------------------+-----------+
|  Logdate   |      Firstart       |      Laststop       | Drivetime |
+------------+---------------------+---------------------+-----------+
| 2018-04-01 | 0000-00-00 00:00:00 | 0000-00-00 00:00:00 | 00:36:25  |
| 2018-04-01 | 2018-04-01 07:43:12 | 2018-04-01 09:43:12 | 00:21:23  |
| 2018-04-01 | 2018-04-01 09:53:27 | 2018-04-01 14:45:11 | 00:54:11  |
+------------+---------------------+---------------------+-----------+
```

I have to group by day and get the min value of Firststart, where it is present.

If Firststart is not present for that event, the value is '0000-00-00 00:00:00' .

Now I have to query to have:

MIN(Firststart) with  the value > '0000-00-00 00:00:00' (if present, otherwise '0000-00-00 00:00:00',) 
and SUM(Drivetime) per Logdate.

By using that query below I always get '0000-00-00 00:00:00' as MIN(firstart),
but I want to get '2018-04-01 07:43:12' for that value,

```
SELECT 
 Logdate,
 MIN(Firststart) AS Firststart,
 MAX(Laststop) AS Laststop,
 SEC_TO_TIME(SUM(TIME_TO_SEC(Drivetime))) AS Drivetime
FROM Logevents
WHERE Logdate >= "2018-04-01"
GROUP BY Logdate
```

Is this possible, and if so, what is the proper syntax?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The trick is to use `NULLIF` to se to NULL all `'0000-00-00 00:00:00'` strings before the `MIN/MAX` aggreagate function, because it will exlude them.

After the aggregation, if there are nulls, we can use `ISNULL` to convert them back to `'0000-00-00 00:00:00'` string.

```
select 
    Logdate, 
    isnull(MIN(nullif(Firststart, '0000-00-00 00:00:00')), '0000-00-00 00:00:00') Firststart, 
    isnull(MAX(nullif(Laststop, '0000-00-00 00:00:00')), '0000-00-00 00:00:00')  Laststop, 
    cast(dateadd(ss, SUM(datediff(ss, 0, Drivetime)), 0) as time(0)) Drivetime
from x
group by Logdate
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
SELECT Logdate, MAX(Firststart) AS Firststart, MAX(Laststop) AS Laststop,
  SEC_TO_TIME(SUM(TIME_TO_SEC(A.Drivetime))) AS Drivetime
FROM
    (SELECT
      Logdate, MIN(Firststart) AS Firststart, MAX(Laststop) AS Laststop,
      SEC_TO_TIME(SUM(TIME_TO_SEC(Drivetime))) AS Drivetime
    FROM Logevents
    WHERE Firststart>'0000-00-00 00:00:00' 
    GROUP BY Logdate
    UNION
    SELECT
      Logdate, MIN(Firststart) AS Firststart, MAX(Laststop) AS Laststop,
      SEC_TO_TIME(SUM(TIME_TO_SEC(Drivetime))) AS Drivetime
    FROM Logevents
    WHERE Firststart='0000-00-00 00:00:00'
    GROUP BY Logdate) A
GROUP BY A.Logdate;
```

See it run on [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/6918ca/4).

Comment: Thanks, but in that case the first drivetime of  00:36:25 will be not considered. I need to have also that in the SUM